# Have a nice travel?

Tags: expressions

I am looking for some kind way of replying to an email when the other person is saying that he will be traveling and asks for more time to complete something.

It appears that "Have a nice day" could have some negative connotations (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57692/what-s-wrong-with-saying-have-a-nice-day), so I am wondering whether saying "Have a nice travel" is a good idea?

Comment: I think your question is kind of unclear. Since you say *"... the other person is saying that he will be traveling and asks for more time to complete something."* So I think you are looking for a phrase that can be used in this situation whether sarcastically or not.

Comment: Is it even correct to say it?

Comment: You could say, "Travel safely."  Or, "I hope you enjoy your travels."  Or, "I hope you enjoy your trip."

Comment: Have a nice journey.

Comment: If you read the answers to the question you linked, I think you'll see essentially unanimous agreement that there's nothing wrong with "Have a nice day". That being said, it's not really applicable when someone's going on a trip that will last more than a day.

Comment: First, please, how much do you care that the other person asks for more time to complete something? The combination seems very different from asking solely about the travelling…

Answer (score 15, accepted):

['Have a safe journey (or trip)'](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Have+a+safe+journey) is one common phrase

> **Have a safe trip** or **Have a safe journey**
>   Be careful and assure that your journey is safe. (Said as someone is about to leave for a trip.)
>
> Bill: Well, we're off for London.
>   Sally: Have a safe trip!
>
> Bill: You're driving all the way to San Francisco?
>   Bob: Yes, indeed.
>   Bill: Well, have a safe trip.
>
> *www.thefreedictionary.com*

Answer (score 15):

How about, "have a nice trip"?

It sounds more natural, as a native English speaker.

Comment: I prefer having a nice trip to having a safe trip, myself.

Answer (score 5):

You can use "Have a safe journey" or "Have a nice trip"

"Bon voyage" is also a great phrase to use. It originated from French.

Answer (score 4):

I will go with ***Bon voyage!***

> *interj.* Used to express farewell and good wishes to a departing traveler. [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Bon+voyage)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a business trip, which sounds likely in the case given, I prefer "Have a safe trip" or "Safe travels".

If its is a holiday/vacation, I go with "Enjoy your trip" or "Enjoy your holiday".

If it is a business trip and I know the person *really* well then I might also use "Enjoy your holiday" in a jocular sense.

Comment: Fine, Keith, and did you notice how few times you've heard anyone else say either 'Have a safe trip' or 'Safe travels'?

To be realistic, you might use 'Travel safely' and how truly is that comparable?

Answer (score 0):

"Have a nice trip" is something formal... "safe trip" give something impression that he is going in some risky place where you are giving him wish to be safe. I prefer to say "Have a nice trip".

Comment: Hi Asim, welcome to ELL SE! If you add some sources into this answer it will make it a really good one. Feel free to read through the [How to Answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) section of the help pages

Answer (score 0):

A "day" is clearly a thing while "travel" is clearly not.

Travel being an abstract concept, not a concrete thing, means there can never be "a travel". Does that make sense?

Grammatically, we might try "have a nice journey/time/trip/voyage…" but "… a nice (anything)" is a dreadful turn of phrase and always to be avoided.

Raj's "Bon voyage" does seem like a great choice, but it should be used with care. For no particular reason, and more so when it's in writing with no tone of voice to clarify it "Bon voyage" can just as easily mean "Good riddance" or simply "Up yours". Oops!

Try for instance "have a safe journey/good time/great trip/fantastic voyage…" or "enjoy your journey/trip/self…"